# what to do about a ridiculous edit

Tags: support

I got a message in my inbox about one of my posts, and found that some anonymous user had edited it.  With the exception of fixing one typo, the edit was useless.  It did not add, improve or clarify anything, and introduced some marginal grammar.  There does not seem to be any way I can post my objections to this edit, and I would like to do so.  The "editor" wasted his/her time, the time of the reviewers, and my time.  Additionally, I am thoroughly offended and wish to express my displeasure.  What can I do?

Comment: Do you mean [this edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8678754)? To be honest, it is not that bad. Is isn't much he/she has changed, but it isn't a waste of time either.

Comment: Frankly, I'd have accepted that edit. It _does_ fix some mistakes in the post... I don't understand why you'd be "offended" about that edit.

Comment: How on Earth is it possible to be 'thoroughly offended' by an edit that enhances the question? Sounds like mere 'pride' rather than actual offence.

Comment: To all:  I agree the edit isn't that bad, and it did fix a typo.  If anyone had asked me I would have said okay, although I didn't see the point; the question was clear enough.  What upset me was not being asked for input.  This unilateral overriding of my post, with no place even to express an objection,  implies that the editor is a smart, wise person who knows best, as compared to little old me who must be ignorant and stupid to have left a typo in the post, not to mention failing to organize it as the editor thought best.

Comment: (continued) The process of simply overriding what someone has written, without their input or consent, is very disrespectful.  And to do it for no good reason as in this case is, as I called it, ridiculous.  It happens I write about 4000 pages of material annual, both marketing and technical, with considerable success, so my writing isn't really that bad.  I don't put as much editing effort into my posts as I do my other material.  I might do that if I had any idea what the post police want, but this example does not tell me, because the changes were so trivial.

Comment: If you had been active at the time, you would have been prompted to review the edit. Edits cannot sit "pending" until the OP (who may never return) decides to review them. If you would have said "Yes" why are you offended that three other people did so, bearing in mind that this site is *collabaritively edited by design*?

Comment: TZHX -- I cannot be active all the time.  But the site does send me emails when there is activity, and I could have responded to one.  If someone doesn't respond in a reasonable time, then they can be presumed to agree and the edit can go forward.  But to inform someone ex post facto, without indicating any method of disagreeing or rolling back, is as I said disrespectful.

Comment: To Santiago - the expression 'mere pride' is very unhelpful.  The main purpose of treating people with courtesy and respect is to let them keep their pride intact.  Everyone has pride and most people get upset when it is trampled on.  On this website it leads to complaints; in other circumstances it can and does lead to fights, murder and lawsuits.  There is nothing "mere" about it.  Please reconsider your own respectful behavior in terms of guarding other people's pride.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't really vent at an anonymous user, but to show that you didn't approve of the edit, just roll it back.  You have the power to do that on any of your own posts if they're edited.

If the behavior persists (i.e. someone else comes along and edits it in a dissatisfactory manner), roll it back and flag for moderator attention.

Comment: Fortunately the question was answered, from the original post which somehow was clear enough that people understood it.  I just needed to know how to respond to the edit situation.  Thanks for this suggestion.

Comment: Betty, if you don't like that edit,  then roll it back, but please don't add such theatrical stuff like "I'm not the author anymore". It is just noise and unimportant for the question itself.

Comment: Is there a button to push to roll it back, or do I have to retype the original?  Re the noise of I'm not the author anymore, I'll point out that in many contexts it is illegal to attribute to one person the writings of someone else.

Comment: @BettyMock:  First, yes there is a way to roll it back under the edit history.  Second, don't reintroduce that text into the question; it does not add any value to the question, and further, the site's content is licensed under [CC-by-SA with attribution required](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).  Your name is still the primary poster, so no one has discounted or discredited your work.  It's simply been remixed, or edited in this case, to read a bit clearer.

Comment: So attribution of the original questioner is required, but attribution of the anonymous editor is not required?  How can that be?

Comment: @BettyMock You're stepping well into the realm of legal jargon, which is above my pay grade.  However, I suppose the question I'd pose would be, "How do you properly attribute someone who has intentionally not identified themselves?"

Comment: @Makoto I read the license.  It says that the material is open source, that anyone can alter it or use it in any way, but that if they do they must credit the original author. Fine.  It does NOT say that anyone may alter the material and credit the alterations to the original author.  That would in fact be illegal for many reasons such as ruining the author's reputation, fraud, etc.  My reading of the license is that edits must be clearly marked as such.  Sometimes they are, which is fine.  But the  editing and attributing the result to the original author is probably a breach of your license.

Comment: Makoto, I have been looking for the rollback feature, and cannot find it.  Could you kindly explain to me how to do it?

Answer (score 9):

I am also "offended". You have now added to the list of people having time wasted by bringing this to meta. Express your personal gripes on tumblr or some other social network -- they seem to be all about people being "offended" over nonsense reasons.

If you don't want such trivial edits on your posts to be approved in future, don't press on the "Post Your Question" button when your post has issues that can be fixed so trivially.

<sub><sub>Don't take this all so seriously. There is now one less issue with your post. Move on. Be excellent to each other.</sub></sub>

Comment: _"such trivial edits"_ For the record: I disagree with the opinion that that edit was trivial. It did fix a couple of flaws. That said, +1.

Comment: @Cerbrus For the record, I didn't actually take the time to look at it. My thorough feeling of being offended paralyzed me with righteous indignation. :)

Comment: To TZHX,  There is a difference between pointing out a problem and a "gripe".  Overriding someone's work and then posting your own verbiage as theirs is, at the least, disrespectful, and at worst illegal and actionable.  That is a problem, and I've posted a possible solution on meta.  If I am offended by this kind of disrespect, so will others be, and that also is a problem.  As to your "solution" that I shouldn't post my questions, I use this site seriously to help me with programming issues, so I am going to post.  I have no interest at all in anyone's grammar -- only in good answers.

Comment: To Cerbrus:  We can disagree about what is trival of course.  What I saw was one harmless typo fixed; and one paragraph moved, and  awkwardly reworded.  If the edit had clarified anything and made it easier for people to answer, or if it had cleaned up a grammatical mess then I wouldn't consider it trivial.  I would even have been glad to learn from it.

Comment: @BettyMock I agree there is a difference. I believe your post falls into the "gripe" category. That you believe someone editing your post to try and make it better is "disrespectful" shows you don't understand how this site is designed to work. That you suggest it is "legally actionable" shows you are being overly dramatic -- which, whether intentional or not -- makes it difficult to fathom what *actual problem* you have.

Comment: TZHX.  The editors may be well meaning, but that doesn't mean they always improve the posts.  Check out meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266901/… meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285779/…; Re the legal aspect, check my answer to Makoto above.  If this is "how the site works" It would take just one really mad user to embroil StackOverflow in expensive litigation.  If there are going to be pre-emptive edits, the procedure for rolling them back should be clearly posted.

Comment: TZHX -- I could have worded the "I am offended" differently, such as "people can be easily offended by .. " Then it might have seemed more like a constructive criticism than a gripe.   But we come from where we are.  In my world of business "I am offended" is not, in the context of my letter, a gripe; it is a signal that there is a problem.  If one person is offended, so are others. So I wrote it that way, not knowing that on this site full of techies it might be taken differently.

Comment: @Betty Your (and others) use of the website is an agreement to be bound by it's terms of service, it's terms of service have you explicitly grant the site irrevocable license to modify any content you provide. There is no legal case to be made that is a practical concern.

Comment: Thank you for this information.  Could you give me a link to the terms of service.  I should clarify that I am not litigious at all.  I believe disagreements between rational people can be resolved with discussion.  In this case I would pleased if StackOverflow would add instructions to the edit page explaining how to object to or roll back the edit; and if the edits from this process were marked as such on the question.  I believe these small changes would improve the site, and avoid lengthy misunderstandings like this one.